# Converting forEach function to map function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, ecmascript-6

Here is my current code which uses `forEach()`:

1.

```
// loop with assignment
userForm.forEach(field => {
    field.value = ''
})
```

2.

```
// if array1 has field which array2 have, assign it
array1.forEach(field => {
    if (Object.keys(array2).indexOf(field.name) > -1) {
      field.value = array2[field.name]
    }
})
```

3.

```
array1.forEach(field => {
    field.shouldShow = false
    field.start = moment(invoice.start).format('YYYY/MM/DD')
    field.end = moment(invoice.end).format('YYYY/MM/DD')
    // ..brabrabra asignment
})
```

Is is possible to turn all `forEach()` functions into `map()` functions?

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: As you foreach over objects and only change the properties of it, it does not make much of a difference. When you use map you have to add `return field`.

Comment: wanna make it more functional like:
array1.map(field => xxxxxx)

Comment: @KevinHu I read you want to convert `forEach` to `map` but what are you trying to achieve in loop? 1st and 3rd can be easily done, but second might not be appropriate. So, what is the use-case? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: function emailClients(clients) {
      clients.filter(isClientActive)
           .forEach(email)    
}

function isClientActive(client) {
  var _clientRecord = database.lookup(client);
  return _clientRecord.isActive();
}
should I change like this?

Answer (score 0):

usage

foreach: This iterates over a list and applies some operation with side effects to each list member (example: saving every list item to the database)

map: This iterates over a list, transforms each member of that list, and returns another list of the same size with the transformed members (example: transforming list of strings to uppercase)

References

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

Found this on web try it

```js
var m = new Map();  
m.set(1, "car");  
m.set(2, "bike");  
m.set("colors", 2);  
m.set({x:1}, 3);  

m.forEach(function (item, key, mapObj) {  
    document.write(item.toString() + "<br />");  
});  

document.write("<br />");  
document.write(m.get(2));
```